# Strolling/pacing back and forth

Tags: translation

How do you express "strolling/pacing back and forth"? For example, if you are waiting for someone in front of a bus stop, you might walk back and forth a bit on a stretch of side walk.

I stumbled across 踱来踱去 *duó lái duó qù* "strolling/pacing back and forth" while doing some reading a while back. However, I'm not sure how common this expression is because it took some effort to type, and the example sentences I could find seem a bit literary.

Are there some more common ways to express this idea?

Comment: jukuu：pacing:6.   
 有人在幕布后踱来踱去。 7.   
 他一面说一面来回走动，聪明的瘦脸上神采焕发。 9.   
 他的顶头上司可能在那踱来踱去，思索着解雇他的辞令呢。11.   
 你一直在来回踱步。   91.那年轻人摇了摇头，又在人行道上垂头丧气地踱来踱去；一看见我朝他的方向走来，就停步看着我。小狗开始晃动尾巴。  99.怎么了,丽莎？你一直来回踱步着。  (more in between 1 and 100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

踱 is a bit formal. 走来走去 or 晃来晃去 will be more colloquial.

Answer (score 1):

**踱步**= **pacing**

来回踱步= pacing around

踱来踱去= pacing back and forth

Since '[pacing](http://www.yourdictionary.com/pacing)' means *"repeatedly walking back and forth across. "* We can say 踱步, 来回踱步 and 踱来踱去 are basically describing the same action.

Example:

在房间里踱步, 在房间里来回踱步, 在房间里踱来踱去

Answer (score 0):

**徘徊**

*ABC*

> V.
>
> 1 pace back and forth

*Oxford*

> 他独自在江边徘徊。
>
> He wandered alone by the river.

Comment: I originally included 徘徊 in my answer, but 徘徊 mainly means "lingering" and "wandering" therefore I deleted it from my post.